# Unable to deploy my full-stack web application. I get SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Tags: sqlite, deployment, web-deployment, node-sqlite3

I am trying to deploy a web application. I have it up and running on my computer, but when I try to deploy it using render.com or Cyclic, I get the following error:

SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

The application is using SQLite3, Express, React and NodeJS. Here is the repo that I am linking: https://github.com/darioospina/yourBvc_sqlite

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

I tried including electron-build, I also created this folder within the sqlite3 folder: "napi-v3-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" because I was getting an error saying that the module wasn't found in that folder, I have tried different solutions I have found here and in different websites but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using cyclic.sh ran into the same issue.

Serverless. No disk access.

[image]